# Find minimum value of $f(x)=\left| x-1 \right|+\left| 2x-1 \right|+\left| 3x-1 \right|+\cdots +\left| 119x-1 \right| $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find the minimum value of

$f(x)=\left| x-1 \right|+\left| 2x-1 \right|+\left| 3x-1 \right|+\cdots +\left| 119x-1 \right| $

Hint given was that for $\frac{1}{n+1}\le x\le \frac{1}{n}$

$f(x)=\left( 60\times 119-n(n+1) \right)x-119+2n$.

But I cannot understand what it means

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. If $\frac{1}{n+1}\le x\le \frac{1}{n}$ with $1\leq n\leq 119$ then $nx-1\leq 0$ and $(n+1)x-1\geq 0$. Hence
$$f(x)=(1-x)+(1-2x)+\cdots +(1-nx)+((n+1)x-1)+\dots+(118x-1)+(119x-1)\\
=\sum_{k=1}^n(1-kx)+\sum_{k=n+1}^{119}(kx-1)=2\sum_{k=1}^n(1-kx)+\sum_{k=1}^{119}(kx-1)\\
=2n-n(n+1)x+\frac{119\cdot 120}{2}x-119=
\left( 60\cdot 119-n(n+1) \right)x-119+2n.$$
Hence $f$ is a continuous function which is linear in each interval $I_n=[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$. This means that the minimum value of $f$ over $I_n$ is attained at one of the end points.
Therefore it suffices to find the minimum of the values 
$$f(1/n)=\left( 60\cdot 119-n(n+1) \right)\cdot (1/n)-119+2n=\frac{7140}{n}+n-120$$
for $n=1,\dots,119$.

P.S. The minimum value should be $f(84)=f(85)=49$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: Mean deviation of a set of numbers is minimum when measured about the median of the set of numbers.